# Zend Form Custom Filter Class not found

Tags: zend-framework, filter, zend-form, zend-form-element

My Custom Zend Form Filter Classes are not being loaded.

The Custom Filter Class name is: **SF_Filter_AlnumDashes** and it resides into:
library/SF/Filter/AlnumDashes.php.

I have configured autoloading for the "SF_" namespace into application.ini:

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "SF_"
```

But when I try to load the Class during Zend Form creation I get error that the class coudn't be found:
**Fatal error: Class 'AlnumDashesUnderscore' not found in...**

Here is the code that is causing the error in the Zend Form class:

```
class Admin_Form_Product_Generalinfo extends SF_Form_Abstract {

    public function init() {

        //set ID Attribute on the form element
        $this->setAttrib('id', 'product_general_info');

        $elementPrefixPaths = array(
                array(
                    array(
                        'prefix' => 'SF_Filter', 
                        'path' => 'SF/Filter/', // 'application/validators' in your case
                        'type' => 'filter',
                    )
                )
            ); 
        $this->addElementPrefixPaths($elementPrefixPaths);

    $this->addElement('text', 'title', array(

            'filters' => array('StringTrim', 'StripTags'),
            'validators' => array(
        array('StringLength', true, array(2, 250)),
            ),
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Title',
            'attribs' => array(
                'id' => 'title',
                'class' => 'inputbox'
             )

    ));

        $this->getElement('title')->addFilter(array(new AlnumDashesUnderscore(), array(1)));
```

}

I have other classes into "SF_" Namespace that get load successfully, calling them from Controllers with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The class is defined as `SF_Filter_AlnumDashes`, but you're trying to create a new instance of `AlnumDashesUnderscore`. These class names need to match:

```
$this->getElement('title')->addFilter(array(new SF_Filter_AlnumDashes(), array(1)));
```

Comment: Well if I do like that I get this Exception:

Exception information:

Message: Invalid filter provided to addFilter; must be string or Zend_Filter_Interface

Comment: Okay, well that's a separate problem. Filters must implement `Zend_Filter_Interface`, so you'll need to modify your custom filter accordingly.

Comment: The Filter Class implements the Zend_Filter_Interface:
`class SF_Filter_AlnumDashes implements Zend_Filter_Interface`

Comment: You also need to pass the filter itself as the parameter, not an array. So you probably want `->addFilter(new SF_Filter_AlnumDashes(), array(1)));`

Comment: I got another problem now and I haven't changed anything in my code.

`Exception caught by form: Plugin by name 'SF_Filter_AlnumDashes' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Filter_: Zend/Filter/ Stack Trace...`